# UITableViewCell Auto Layout Width Not Working With UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm having problem with the auto layout constraints in UITableViewCell when using with UIBezierPath. My cell wont go full width. You can see the different between Image 1 and Image 2. Image 2 I didn't add rounding corners.

**Image 1**
[image: With UIBezierPath]

**Image 2**
[image: Without UIBezierPath]

Previously, I'm having the same problem with UIBezierPath in UiView (you can see the first 2 UIView with "0"). The workaround I'm using is to mask the rounding corners in viewDidLayoutSubviews like below codes:-

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    UIView *container =  (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:100101];
    [container setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"ffffff"]];
    [self setMaskTo:container byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];
}
```

But now I'm stuck in UITableViewCell because I cant add the rounding corners in viewDidLayoutSubviews. My codes as below:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myData";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    MyWClass *w = [_wData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIView *container = (UIView *) [cell viewWithTag:200001];
    [container setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:w.bgColor]];
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:container.layer.bounds
                                                   byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
                                                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = container.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    container.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#efeff4"]];
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#e4e4e8"].CGColor;
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 0;

    return cell;
}
```

I try to add `[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];` but still same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `container.layer.masksToBounds = YES;` or `-clipsToBounds`

Comment: @0yeoj tried, still not working

Comment: If you scroll your cells offscreen, do they fix themselves when you scroll them back?

Comment: @stefandouganhyde no

Comment: Would you be able to post the part where you create the view with the tag `200001`?

Comment: @stefandouganhyde view with the tag 200001 is the view with blue, green, white, white, green and red colors. Created using storyboard in prototype cell.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am having this problem as well!

Comment: @Erik Yes. I redo the view and constraint back because previously it was in UiView -> UiView. So I remove the second UiView and it works.

Comment: @skycrew, I am having exact this problem, can you please explain a little bit more about the solution?

Comment: @Tulon I remove extra UiView on top of base UiView

Comment: @skycrew, Thanks for your reply. In my case I have to remove the two side rounded corner code (using `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect`) from `- (void)awakeFromNib` method to `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method in `customTableViewCell`, and It is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

below logic working for me:

set your UIview width equal to cell width.

Ex: `container.frame.size.width = cell.frame.size.width`

Answer (score 0):

Try `UIBezierPath` inside main thread ( See the following **Swift 5** solution )

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
             {
                let Cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell") as! MyTableViewCell
                Cell.selectionStyle = .none
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: Cell.contentView.bounds,
                                                       byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight],
                                                       cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
                    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
                    shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
                    Cell.contentView.layer.mask = shape
                           
                }
                return Cell
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, initialize your Bezier path inside of your ViewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear and just make the atribution on cellForRow atIndexPath

Like this

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer.init()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        self.maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.tableView.layer.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.topLeft, UIRectCorner.topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize.init(width: 26.0, height: 26.0)).cgPath

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellButtons",         for: indexPath)
            
            
       cell.layer.mask = self.maskLayer
       return cell
}
```